# When destroying and recreating activity, handler is still running in old, destroyed activity instance

Tags: android, android-activity, thread-safety, android-lifecycle, android-handler

I'm trying to have my app display a continuous value, even through activity destruction and recreation. I use a background thread to maintain FPS, basically just sending messages to a handler. When the activity is destroyed and recreated, a new handler is created and sent to a new instance of the background thread. When messages are received, however, they appear to be being received by the original handler, running in the "destroyed" activity. I'd really appreciate if someone more experienced than me could weigh in on this!

My Code (I know there's more than a bit of it, but almost everything relevant happens in onCreate):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

final static int UPDATE_DISPLAY = 1;

//View Pager declarations
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 4; //Number of viewPager pages
private ViewPager mPager;
private ScreenSlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private MainThread thread;
Fragment[] fragmentMap = new Fragment[NUM_PAGES];
//End view pager declarations

globalData gd;

private Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        //TESTING-------------
        System.out.println("Received message from background thread.");
        System.out.println("Handler receiving message is: "+this.toString());
        System.out.println("Handler is running in activity: "+MainActivity.this.toString());
        //---------------

        if (msg.what == UPDATE_DISPLAY){
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalGas)).
                    setText("Gas: "+UnitValuePair.convertNumberToString(gd.getGasOwned()));
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalRock)).
                    setText("Rock: "+UnitValuePair.convertNumberToString(gd.getRockOwned()));
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalMetal)).
                    setText("Metal: "+UnitValuePair.convertNumberToString(gd.getMetalOwned()));
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("CREATING MainActivity");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    Button resetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resetData();
        }
    });

    //Instantiate ViewPager and PagerAdapter
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

    //Attach tablayout to view pager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);

    //Init variable
    gd = globalData.getInstance();

    //Check if new game, and if so, init all base and actual values
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //If first start, then init vals and mark that it has been started in shared preferences
    boolean startedBefore = sharedPref.getBoolean("startedBefore", false);
    Log.d("TEST", "Value of startedBefore boolean is:" + Boolean.toString(startedBefore));
    if (!startedBefore)
    {
        gd.initVals();
        gd.storeData();
        gd.setNewGame(false);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("startedBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Restoring data");
        gd.restoreData();
    }

    //TESTING---------
    System.out.println("Handler seen by activity is: "+handler.toString());
    System.out.println("New Activity is : "+this.toString());
    //--------------------

    //Start main update thread
    thread = new MainThread((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mainContainer), gd, handler, getApplicationContext());
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    System.out.println("PAUSING MainActivity");
    super.onPause();
    gd.storeData();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("RESUMING MainActivity");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
        //If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle
        //back button. Calls finish() on activity and pops the back stack
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem (int position)
    {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                CreationFragment newFragment0 = CreationFragment.newInstance(0);
                fragmentMap[0] = newFragment0;
                return newFragment0;

            case 1:
                UniverseFragment newFragment1 = UniverseFragment.newInstance(1);
                fragmentMap[1] = newFragment1;
                return newFragment1;

            default:
                return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    //Provides the titles of the fragments for use in tabLayout
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title=" ";
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                title="Create";
                break;
            case 1:
                title="Universe";
                break;
            case 2:
                title="Upgrades";
                break;
            case 3:
                title="Stats";
                break;
        }

        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    System.out.println("DESTROYING MainActivity");
    //handler = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void resetData()
{
    gd.initVals();
    gd.setVisibilityChangedDisplay(true);
    gd.setVisibilityChangedInv(true);
    gd.setChangedDisplay(true);
    gd.setChangedInv(true);
}

}
```

The logcat:

The original handler, 6402d8e, starts out running in activity 108d9af. The activity is paused, destroyed, and recreated as activity 3112cf7. A new handler, 70420f6, is created and sent to a new background thread. The background thread starts sending messages, and they are received, but the handler receiving them says it is the original one, 6402d8e, still running in activity 108d9af!

```
04-09 20:17:41.471 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Received message from background thread.
04-09 20:17:41.471 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler receiving message is: Handler (com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity$1) {6402d8e}
04-09 20:17:41.471 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler is running in activity: com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity@108d9af
04-09 20:17:41.502 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: PAUSING MainActivity
04-09 20:17:41.502 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth D/TEST: Storing data
04-09 20:17:41.741 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: DESTROYING MainActivity
04-09 20:17:41.759 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: CREATING MainActivity
04-09 20:17:41.759 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for CreationFragment{a0042e2 #1 id=0x7f0d006d} not updated inline; expected state 1 found 0
04-09 20:17:41.759 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for UniverseFragment{66e2681 #2 id=0x7f0d006d} not updated inline; expected state 1 found 0
04-09 20:17:41.775 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth D/TEST: Value of startedBefore boolean is:true
04-09 20:17:41.775 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Restoring data
04-09 20:17:41.775 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth D/TEST: Retrieving data
04-09 20:17:41.775 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler seen by activity is: Handler (com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity$1) {70420f6}
04-09 20:17:41.775 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: New Activity is : com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity@3112cf7
04-09 20:17:41.775 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: New thread created. Handler seen by thread is: Handler (com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity$1) {70420f6}
04-09 20:17:41.805 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: RESUMING MainActivity
04-09 20:17:41.811 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Received message from background thread.
04-09 20:17:41.811 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler receiving message is: Handler (com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity$1) {6402d8e}
04-09 20:17:41.811 29339-29339/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler is running in activity: com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity@108d9af
```

----UPDATE------
The new activity starts the new thread, but the one sending messages has the id of the old one that should have been destroyed

```
04-10 10:43:41.149 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: New Activity is : com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity@49e83d5
04-10 10:43:41.149 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: New thread created with id: 23410
04-10 10:43:41.149 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler seen by new thread is: Handler (com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity$1) {cf3308c}
04-10 10:43:41.149 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Starting thread with id: 23410
04-10 10:43:41.180 19846-19878/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Thread sending message is: 23405
04-10 10:43:41.188 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: RESUMING MainActivity
04-10 10:43:41.194 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Received message from background thread.
04-10 10:43:41.194 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler receiving message is: Handler (com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity$1) {6402d8e}
04-10 10:43:41.194 19846-19846/com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth I/System.out: Handler is running in activity: com.kessler.alexi.stellargrowth.MainActivity@108d9af
```

-----ANSWER------
It turns out it was just an issue of changing onDestroy to

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    System.out.println("DESTROYING MainActivity");
    thread.setRunning(false);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The thread run code, shown below, acquired the lock and basically never shut down as the boolean running was not automatically changed. When the new thread was started, it tried to acquire the lock, failed, and the old one started up again.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread "+this.getId()+" started.");
    if (MainThread.lock.tryLock()) {
        System.out.println("Thread "+this.getId()+" acquired lock");
        try {
            long tickCount = 0L;
            while (running) {
                tickCount++;
                controlFPS(tickCount);
                update();
            }
        } finally {
            MainThread.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not remove the handler call in onPause() or onDestroy() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by removing the call. I tried setting the handler to null, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the thread as a private field in the class so it can be reached by all methods in the class and then :

In           onDestroy()   method

Use

```
              thread.Abort()
```

Comment: I don't think that thread.Abort() is valid syntax, but I did try thread.interrupt(), which didn't change anything. As far as I can tell, when I call start on the new thread, it sets the old one running.